# Adjoint of an everywhere defined linear operator must be bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, adjoint-operators, closed-graph

I saw the theorem 1.8 in the book [Spectral Theory of ...](https://bookstore.ams.org/surv-73/16) that

If $T$ is a linear operator from the Hilbert space $H$ to another Hilbert space $H_1$, and the domain of definition of T, denoted by $\mathcal{D}(T)$, is $H$, then the adjoint of $T$, denoted by $T^*$, is bounded.

Here, the domain of definition of $T^*$, denoted by $\mathcal{D}(T^*)$, is the set of all $v\in H_1$ such that there exists $v^*\in H$ with $(Tu, v) = (u, v^*)$ for all $u\in \mathcal{D}(T)$.

There is no proof from the book. What I am trying is to use the [closed graph theorem](https://www.math.uzh.ch/gorodnik/fa17/lecture10.pdf). First, we can show that $T^*$ is a closed linear operator. Next, to apply the closed graph theorem, we need $\mathcal{D}(T^*)$ be closed, but I can not show that.

Do you have any idea? Is the theorem true? How to prove it?

Comment: You need boundeness of $T$. It is not true that any linear operator defined on whole of $H$ has a  bounded adjoint.

Comment: I also suspect that it is false. Do you have a counter-example?

Comment: Let $f$ be a dis-continuous linear functional and take $Tx=f(x)x_0$ for a fixed non-zero vector $x_0$.

Comment: In many books 'linear operators' are always bounded. They specifically say 'unbounded operator' when the their linear maps are not bounded.

Comment: Thanks! I have just figured out your example. So, we can take $T$ as any unbounded linear operator defined everywhere from $H$. Then, suppose $T^*$ is bounded, we can find that $T$ is also bounded, thus to a contradiction. Is that right?

Comment: If $T^*$ (instead of $T$) is defined on the entire space, then $T$ is bounded.

Comment: You are right! The theorem from the book is possibly misprinted.